# How do I use the filesystem on a Raspberry Pi Pico without Thonny?

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm starting to use Raspberry Pi Picos more and I think Thonny is holding me back. I want to mount it as a device on my Mac so I can use terminal commands, or finder if possible, to navigate through it. I've tried accessing the REPL, and can do so, but that is only a MicroPython shell, so it's not useful for this. Does the MicroPython shell have a function for files?

Comment: There is no "normal shell" on a Pico; these are not full computers running Linux like other Pi models.  With the MicroPython firmware installed, MicroPython is *all that you have to work with*.

Comment: Thanks, but if that's the case, how does Thonny access files, and is it replicable?

Answer (score 1):

You can recompile MicroPython with the USB mass storage interface enabled, or
maybe find a prebuilt version that has it enabled.  I searched for `USB_MSC` in the "ports/rp2" folder of the MicroPython source code and I discovered that they enable the mass storage interface for Arduino Nano RP2040 Connect board.  Even though you don't have that particular board, you can try installing its MicroPython version on your Pico and it will probably be compatible enough that it will work for you:

https://micropython.org/download/ARDUINO_NANO_RP2040_CONNECT/

When you are running a version of MicroPython with the USB mass storage interface enabled, you'll be able to interact with the files on it just like any other USB drive.  So you'll be able to navigate to it in your terminal and also Finder.

Alternatively, you can use [mpremote](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/reference/mpremote.html).